# Triggering gui update in Eclipse (table not expanding as it should)

Tags: java, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a table in my Eclipse plugin that isn't stretching out vertically when it's data is changed. I do a `viewer.refresh()` to display the new data, but the table only shows one row.

If I minimize the window and restore it then the table grows to display all rows. What do I need to call to trigger than same type of gui re-layout?

(table is in a GridLayout, set to grow in both directions)

Comment: Did you try calling `layout()` or `layout(true, true)` on the parent `Composite` of the viewer?

Comment: Thanks @Baz, I figured there was something like that but I just wasn't finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is caused by the fact, that the parent doesn't know when the child requires more space.

You can force the parent to recalculate its `Layout` (and with that ask the child for the required size) by calling either of these methods:

- [`Composite.layout()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html#layout%28%29):

  > If the receiver has a layout, asks the layout to lay out (that is, set the size and location of) the receiver's children. If the receiver does not have a layout, do nothing.
- [`Composite.layout(boolean)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html#layout%28boolean%29):

  > If the receiver has a layout, asks the layout to lay out (that is, set the size and location of) the receiver's children. If the argument is true the layout must not rely on any information it has cached about the immediate children. If it is false the layout may (potentially) optimize the work it is doing by assuming that none of the receiver's children has changed state since the last layout. If the receiver does not have a layout, do nothing.
- [`Composite.layout(boolean, boolean)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html#layout%28boolean,boolean%29):

  > If the receiver has a layout, asks the layout to lay out (that is, set the size and location of) the receiver's children. If the changed argument is true the layout must not rely on any information it has cached about its children. If it is false the layout may (potentially) optimize the work it is doing by assuming that none of the receiver's children has changed state since the last layout. If the all argument is true the layout will cascade down through all child widgets in the receiver's widget tree, regardless of whether the child has changed size. The changed argument is applied to all layouts. If the all argument is false, the layout will not cascade down through all child widgets in the receiver's widget tree. However, if a child is resized as a result of a call to layout, the resize event will invoke the layout of the child. Note that a layout due to a resize will not flush any cached information (same as layout(false)).